# can't connect mongoDB to localhost

Tags: mongodb

[image]

hey there I don't know why the server refuse to connect to mongo local host and the same problem also for robomongo =[. I was looking for the same error in this site and others but no answer is relevant...I thought it might happened because robomongo is also running and I uninstalled it but...it didn't solve it...I'm using windows 10. tried to do from mongo's directory mongod.exe and it didn't work than mongo.exe but also didn't work...can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

run the MongoDB you need to open another command prompt and use the following command. “C:\Experiments\MongoDB\MongoDbServer\bin>mongo”. It will show the version of MongoDb and connected database, By default it is test. Other window will show one connection is open.

[Read this Article](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/858908/mongodb-with-net-setup-and-crud-operations)

Comment: are you sure this is also for windows? cause windows don't know the command mongo but "mongo.exe" from it's bin directory...

Comment: Yes, check the article.